# Defining a subtable and then query from that table using SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with many columns, and I want to count the unique values of each column. I know that I can do

```
SELECT sho_01, COUNT(*) from sho GROUP BY sho_01 
UNION ALL 
SELECT sho_02, COUNT(*) from sho GROUP BY sho_02 
UNION ALL
....
```

Here `sho` is the table and `sho_01`,.... are the individual columns. This is BigQuery by the way, so they use `UNION ALL`.

Next, I want to do the same thing, but for a subset of `sho`, say `SELECT * FROM sho WHERE id in (1,2,3)`. Is there a way where I can create a subtable first, and then query the subtable? Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM sho WHERE id IN (1,2,3)) AS t1;
SELECT sho_01, COUNT(*) from t1 GROUP BY sho_01 
UNION ALL 
SELECT sho_02, COUNT(*) from t1 GROUP BY sho_02 
UNION ALL
....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the columns are all of the same type.  If so, you can simplify this using arrays:

```
select el.which, el.val, count(*)
from (select t1.*,
             array[struct('sho_01' as which, sho_01 as val),
                   struct('sho_2', show_02),
                   . . .
                  ] as ar
      from t
     ) t cross join
     unnest(ar) el
group by el.which, el.val;
```

You can then easily filter however you want by adding a `where` clause before the `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and allows you to avoid manual typing of column names or even knowing them in advance

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') column, 
  SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] value,
  COUNT(1) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'))) kv
GROUP BY column, value
-- ORDER BY column, value
```